# Pursuit curves and arc length question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, plane-curves, mathematical-modeling, classical-mechanics

I am studying pursuit curves where a fast pirate ship which pursues a heavily
laden treasure ship which tracks along a straight line. The ratio of the speeds of the
ships is r > 1 (which is fixed) and the pirate captain spies the treasure ship initially at a distance d km away.

There s a step within the calculations thatI am failing to understand:

[image]

I do not understand why or how the speed is equal to r(dY/dt)

Comment: What is $Y$?${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Just read the same article Solving the basic pursuit problem by Peter Hagstrom.
The trade ship goes straight along the $Y$-axis (see the pic.) so its speed is $dy/dt$.
The pirate moves in a plane, both its coordinates change, that's why $ds/dt$. And it is $r$ times more than the trade ship speed.
As for me I study the asymptotics of the length of the pursuit curve when $r\gg1$.

Yuri V. Osipov
prof., Chair of Applied Math., Moscow University of Civil Engineering> Russia